# Trying to perform SQL Query to populate select menu using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my code:

```
//Logic....
$companyId = $_POST['var1'];
global $db;
$query = "SELECT firstname, surname FROM contact WHERE directorycompany_id = " . $companyId;
$result = $db->query($query);
$total = $result->num_rows;
?>

<!-- HTML -->
<option value=""><?= $total; ?></option>
```

I am trying to make an `ajax` request when a user selects an option from a dropdown menu. The idea is that the company id is passed as a parameter to the remote script and the `database` is queried using this `id` to return the contacts that work for that company.

This is my page:

```
<p>
    <label>Company Name</label>
    <?php echo SelectBuilder::getDirectoryCompany('companylist', '', 'test') ?>
</p>

<p>
    <label>Columnist Name</label>
    <?php echo SelectBuilder::getDirectoryCompanyStaff('directorystaff_id', $companyId, $objectStaffId, 'test1') ?>
</p>
```

This is the `script`:

```
<script>
    $('#test').change(function() {
            var companyId = $(this).val();
            console.log(companyId);// <---  Pass this to the ajax page as a parameter
            $('#test1').load('pages/ajax/company_dropdown.php', {var1: companyId});
    });
</script>
```

For the most part it works fine. I can call the file, pass the company id as a parameter and output the company id as the option in a select box. However I am trying to populate the select box with the first name and last name of all contacts that work for that company.

Currently I am getting this error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\xxx.tld\pages\ajax\company_dropdown.php on line 12
```

Comment: This is the wrong line: `$result = $db->query($query);`have you tried to do `var_dump($db);`. It seems like even after having called `global $db` it has no value. Maybe it is not the right variable name.

Comment: Always prepare user input! http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/3361444)

Comment: @ValentinMercier just did a `var_dump` on the `$db` variable, it would appear it is being set to `null`. I will try to address this situation.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was very simple I forgot to `include` the file that actually initializes the connection to the `database`. Once this was done I modified the way I was looping through my results and it worked fine.